# Are variables re-initialized each time a function in an external file is called in Python 2.7

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I currently import a function from a larger file I have written - e.g.:

```
     from my_other_file import my_function
```

the function that I am importing uses a dictionary that is initialized elsewhere within `my_other_file` (i.e. at the top of my code I import a CVS file into a dictionary, which is then used by the function).

If i repeatedly call this function (for example when iterating over a loop), will the dictionary be repeatedly re-initialized each time? (or once it has been initialized, it can be called by that function at a later time). I ask because the CSV file the dictionary is crated from is rather large (50MB), and thus I suspect my code will be highly inefficient if this must be read the file in every time the function is called. If it would normally be re-initialized, what would be a way of preventing this from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, importing a module multiple times only executes the module code just once.

Importing really is just creating a reference to the imported names for your importing code to use. *Loading* the module is done just once, with the result stored in `sys.modules`, in order to support the name importing.

See the [`import` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> The basic `import` statement (no `from` clause) is executed in two steps:
>
> 1. find a module, loading and initializing it **if necessary**
> 2. define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the `import` statement occurs.

Emphasis mine; once loaded you don't need to load again.

Comment: Would this be the same case if for example `def foo(): import bar`? Would the initialization be done agian each time you called `foo()`?

Comment: @IanAuld: no, because `import bar` only adds the name `bar` to the local namespace. Python will still only load the module once, so that there is something to create the references *to*.

Comment: thanks!! just to follow up, when would the the variables referenced in the imported function be initialized? ...when it is imported, or when it is first called? [interested because there may be changes to the external data that the variables are created from between importing the function, and first calling it]

Comment: @kyrenia: when the module is loaded (i.e. the initialisation stage).